# Is MySQL C++ Connector access to remote database possible?

Tags: c++, mysql, database, mysql-connector

I am accessing a MySQL database within a C++ app using MySQL C++ Connector.  It works fine if I have the C++ and the MySQL on the same machine.  So, something like the following code works fine:

```
sql::Connection             *_con;
sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver    *_driver;
_driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
_con = _driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "user", "password");
```

However, I can't seem to access the database if it is located on another machine.  So, something like this:

```
sql::Connection             *_con;
sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver    *_driver;
_driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
_con = _driver->connect("tcp://somesite.com:3306", "user", "password");
```

Is it just not possible or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does the remote machine have the port for MySQL forwarded properly, and allow remote connections on the user you're trying to connect with?

Comment: I have the port forwarded.  See the answer from Glen.  I had the DB set for local access only.  Once I changed that, it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you accidentally setup your users so that they can only access your DB from the local machine?

Did you do

```
create user 'user'@'127.0.0.1' ...
```

or

```
create user 'user'@'%' ....
```

If you did the first then you won't be able to log on from a different machine.

Did you also grant the privileges correctly?

See the MySQL [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html) for a more in depth explanation on how to do this correctly

Answer (score 1):

I have done this through a VPN so I am assuming it is possible. Are you using the correct port?

Comment: I'm using the same port and I port forward from the router to the machine with the MySQL db.  I tried with both machines on the same LAN and use the LAN's IP address, e.g. 192.168.0.2.  That didn't work either.